# Can someone explain what the syntax means when defining a jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am reading up on creating custom jQuery plugins and am a little confused as to the meaning of the following syntax:

```
(function($){  
    $.fn.truncate = function() {  
        return this.each(function() { 
        });
     };
})(jQuery);
```

I understand that function($) is an anonymous function that accepts the $. I just don't quite understand why this function is wrapped in brackets and how the following sets of brackets with jQuery in them...work.

Comment: Typical programmer answer: Yes, someone can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not safe to assume that `$` is owned by the jQuery library. Some other javascript libraries/users may/do use that identifier for other purposes. However, `jQuery` is always the jQuery library (barring any evildoers).

This anonymous function handily and safely exposes the `$` shortcut as jQuery by making it a local parameter to the anonymous function. Since parameters will override any globals only for the scope of a function this will not affect any other user/library code outside of it.

Finally, where the anonymous function is executed `jQuery` is passed in as the first paramter to fill `$`.

So when boiled down, this is just a shortcut taken by plugin developers so that they can safely and reliably use `$`; if you don't mind using `jQuery` everywhere instead then this is totally optional.

Answer (score 5):

The following parameters with jQuery are just executing the anonymous function and passing in jQuery as the $ parameter.  This ensures that $ = jQuery just incase window.$ doesn't equal jQuery.

Here is a rewrite of the code that might make more sense:

```
function myFunc($) {   
 $.fn.truncate = function() {   
    return this.each(function() {   
 });   
}

myFunc(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 4):

The surrounding parentheses create an anonymous function to which the `$` symbol references the global `jQuery` object.

`$.fn.truncate` - This means that you are extending the `jQuery` object to include a new function called `truncate`.
**Usage** `$( '#someElement' ).truncate();`