# What does it mean whenever a function ends with })(jQuery);?

Tags: jquery

I tried googleing, but Google doesn't seem to care about parentheses...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458283/in-javascript-what-does-this-syntax-mean and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309614/what-does-this-javascript-jquery-syntax-mean SO has its own search. I found these answer using the title of your question.

Comment: nice you asked this question , we all use this and don't know what it does. I got it clarfied now.

Comment: @gov - This question is asked all the time. Here's another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937227/jquery-what-does-function-jquery-mean and another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976089/can-someone-explain-what-the-syntax-means-when-defining-a-jquery-plugin and another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464635/what-does-function-jquery-do-mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see this:

```
(function($) {
    // ...code using $...
})(jQuery);
```

It's doing two things:

1. Defining an anonymous function that uses `$` as its reference to jQuery.
2. Calling it, passing in `jQuery`.

You could do it like this:

```
function foo($) {
    // ...code using $...
}
foo(jQuery);
```

...but that creates an unnecessary symbol.

All of this is because jQuery has the symbol `jQuery` and the symbol `$`, but it's not uncommon for people to use [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) to tell jQuery to return `$` back to whatever it was when jQuery loaded, because a couple of other popular libraries (Prototype and MooTools, to name two) use `$` and this lets someone use those libraries *and* jQuery together. But you can still use `$` within your function, because the argument shadows whatever that symbol means outside the function.

Comment: why use an anonymous function? If it's anonymous and not reuseable, why make it a function? why not use expressions?

Comment: @polyhedron - This function is meant to run only once, so no need for a name. The point T.J. is making is that `$` becomes a local variable inside the function, where it references the global `jQuery` variable. If you have `$` as a global variable, there will be a conflict if another library is using the same global variable name. This way it is private, and therefore protected.

Comment: @polyhedron: In JavaScript, *only* functions can create new scope, so you have to use a function if you want to create a private variable.

Answer (score 1):

It basically automatically invokes the anonymous/lambda function defined and supplies the `jQuery` reference to it.

Pretty much the same as `functionCall(jQuery)` except you define it and invoke it in the same line/expression.

Answer (score 1):

Usually these are of the form...

```
(function($) {
    // do something with $
})(jQuery);
```

Which means that the function is actually doing something with `jQuery` (it defines `function(a) {...}` and then passes `jQuery` in as `a`), but it wants to be able to use `$` instead `jQuery` inside the function.

This allows things like `$(this)` and so on *even if jQuery is invoked in No-Conflict mode* (and thus `$` wouldn't refer to jQuery normally).